# I want to store the database values of each cell in different variables variables C#??

Tags: c#

I want to store of each cell values in different variables in c# or know what the data is exists in database against Finger_id in another table bank table ..

```
        string queryString = "SELECT b.bank_id  from bank_tbl b  JOIN login_tbl l  ON l.finger_id = b.finger_id WHERE l.passcode = " + pass + " ";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ZIAULHAQ\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = ATM; Integrated Security = True"))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Call Read before accessing data. 
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    reader.Read();

                    int bid1 = cell1;
                    int bid2 = cell2;
                    int bid3 = cell3;
                    // Call Close when done reading.
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
if (bid1 == Value)
        {

            BankHblButton.Show();
        }



        }
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly, MSDN has examples of how to read data from a `SqlDataReader`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx  Specifically you would use numeric or string indexes on the `IDataRecord` object in `reader`.

Comment: Note also that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You should look into "parameterized queries" in ADO.NET.

Comment: C# fully supports _Object Orientated Programming_, so you can take each row from your `reader` and build a **Collection**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `reader` is reading a record, you can get the values of that record by the `IDataRecord` interface on `reader`.  Something like this:

```
// declare your variables in the scope where you need them
int bid1 = 0;
int bid2 = 0;
// etc.

if (reader.Read())
{
    bid1 = reader.GetInt32(0);
    bid2 = reader.GetInt32(1);
    // etc.
}
reader.Close();

// You can now use your bid* variables
```

**Note** however that your *current query* is only selecting *one value* (per row) from your database.  So, contrary to what your question/code implies, there is no "cell 2" or "cell 3" or any thereafter.

If you instead meant to get *rows*, then you would re-structure this a bit.  You would want a *collection* instead of individual variables, and you would populate it with a loop.  Something like this:

```
// declare your variables in the scope where you need them
List<int> bids = new List<int>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    bids.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
}
reader.Close();

// You can now use your bid list
```

Comment: how to use these values one by one in in decision making??? 
if (bids == 1 )
            {

                BankHblButton.Show();
            }
if (bids == 2 )
            {

                BankABLButton.Show();
            }

Comment: @ZiaUlhaq: Do you mean in my second example?  Well, the *entire collection* won't equal `1`.  But a single element *from* the collection might: `if (bids[0] == 1)`

Comment: @ZiaUlhaq: And what's stopping you from doing that?  If you've made some attempt to do that and it's not working in some specific way, that sounds like a good candidate for a Stack Overflow question.  The question you have asked here has already been answered.

Comment: i have one more problem i am stuck in login page i used picture as a login where the user identity is picture and passcode if both are match then login  I FOLLOW  some tutorial but cannot fix ..

Comment: @ZiaUlhaq: If you're having a specific problem with specific code you've written then I would encourage you to open a new question about that.  A comment thread doesn't make for a good tutorial.

Comment: i have one more problem i am stuck in login page i used picture as a login where the user identity is picture and passcode if both are match then login  I FOLLOW  some tutorial but cannot fix ..

Comment: private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
         
               SetValueForText1 = Convert.ToInt32(PasscodeTextBox.Text);
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select finger_id from login_tbl where finger='"+pictureBox.Image.RawFormat+"' AND passcode='" +PasscodeTextBox.Text + "'", conn);

                 DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

                sda.Fill(dt);


                if (dt.Rows.Count==1)

                {
this.Hide();
banks ss = new banks();
    ss.Show();

 }

Comment: @ZiaUlhaq: Please stop spamming the comment thread.  If you have another question, ask it as a separate Stack Overflow question.  Be sure to include information about the problem in that question.  "I have a problem" isn't something we can answer, but you if can describe the problem then we can help you.

Comment: thats my code where image is not converted int binary stream ?? what step i can do .. i shall be very thankfull . i am doing my final year project ...

Comment: @ZiaUlhaq: Nobody can help you if you won't listen.